# Remove border from previous image when next image is clicked and set as main image. Flutter

Tags: flutter

From the image below, i want to set border around the first image when the page loads and also set it as the main image. Once the next image is clicked, it has to be set as the main image with the border around it. I am trying to achieve this in flutter and the list of images were built using a ListView builder. Can anyone be of help. The heroImage widget depends on the image selection from the images widget and on page load, the heroImage must be set to the first image in the images widget.
[image]

```
// Selected image tile being used in the listView
class SelectedImageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final String imageAsset;
  final BoxDecoration decoration;

  SelectedImageTile({
    this.onTap,
    this.imageAsset,
    this.decoration
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        decoration: decoration,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          child: Image.asset(
            imageAsset,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget heroImage() {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/image-1.png',
        height: 350,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        fit: BoxFit.cover
      ),
    );
 }

  Widget images() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 75,
      child: ListView.builder(
        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final galleryImage = galleryImages[index];

          return SelectedImageTile(
            imageAsset: galleryImage,
            onTap: () {},
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: EShopColors.primary),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: galleryImages.length,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `images()` widget to a `StateFulWidget`

Create a variable `selectedImage` and set it to URL of the image tapped (when tapped)

And finally add a condition to the border of the image tile.

```
class Images extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImagesState createState() => _ImagesState();
}

class _ImagesState extends State<Images> {
    var selectedImage = galleryImages[0]

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
    height: 75,
    child: ListView.builder(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        final galleryImage = galleryImages[index];

        return SelectedImageTile(
          imageAsset: galleryImage,
          onTap: () {
            this.selectedImage = galleryImage;
            setState(() {});
          },
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border:galleryImage==this.selectedImage? Border.all(color: EShopColors.primary):null,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        );
      },
      itemCount: galleryImages.length,
    ),
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do i pass the selected image to the main image since it will be outside it's scope?

Comment: Thank you very much. You are really a life saver. It is working fine. There was no need making the images() widget stateful. Thanks man!!